# Know if package X.Y.Z is running in Android

Tags: android

After searching through all similar **outdated** answers which use `getRunningAppProcesses()` that returns only the ***current*** running process (as of android 5.5.1 AFAIK) , I gave up.

I need to simply know if a user is running "App x" or "App y", Having the package names or the few apps the user wants to check for, using android 6.0.
This : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html looks like a promising solution, but I couldn't get it to work. simply didn't know what parameters are needed!.

Anyone had experience with that before?
Thanks!

Comment: Try out this library: https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android 5 you need to use the [UsageStatsManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) to achieve what you want...

Here is what I do :

1st you need to declare access to usageStats in your manifest file :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

2nd you need to ask the user to give you the access to usage stats :

```
//test whether you do not already have access : 
private static final int USAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 8947;

if (!Utilities.canGetUsageStatistics(getApplicationContext()))
{
    // if no access, bring the user to the setting :
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, USAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
}
```

3rd, wherever you want to know what's going on, here I want to know what is the app actually running on top, so I use something like this:

```
String topPackage = Utilities.getTopPackage(getApplicationContext());
```

And at least, the Utilities class used to handle those calls. Althought this is designed to get only the top-most running package, you can adapt this code to gather more informations about other running apps :

```
public class Utilities {

    public static String getTopPackage(Context context) {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21)
        {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            return tasks.get(0).processName;
        }
        else
        {
            List<UsageStats> usageStats = getUsageStats(context, 43200000);

            if (usageStats == null || usageStats.size() == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }

            /* here you can do what you want with 
            the usageStats list of processes... */

            RecentUseComparator mRecentComp = new RecentUseComparator();
            Collections.sort(usageStats, mRecentComp);
            return usageStats.get(0).getPackageName();
        }
    }


    public static List<UsageStats> getUsageStats(Context context, long forTime)
    {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
            UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            List<UsageStats> usageStats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST, ts - forTime, ts);
            return usageStats;
        }
        return null;
    }


    static class RecentUseComparator implements Comparator<UsageStats>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(UsageStats lhs, UsageStats rhs) {
            return (lhs.getLastTimeUsed() > rhs.getLastTimeUsed()) ? -1 : (lhs.getLastTimeUsed() == rhs.getLastTimeUsed()) ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }

    public static boolean canGetUsageStatistics(Context context) 
    {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
                AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
                int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
                return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check if a package is running or not rather than just getting the top package name ?

Comment: You might have to make some deductions.
From the list you get for the last 72 hours in my example : List<UsageStats> usageStats = getUsageStats(context, 43200000); you could analyse all the UsageStats objects retrieved, and maybe on a longer period of time... A [UsageStat](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html) object has a getLastTimeUsed() method for example... At worst maintain a list from your service...

Comment: I looped through the list and returned true if the package name is there. thanks!